# Censored regression but dependent variable is sum of two censored variables

Tags: regression, censoring

Suppose we have two censored variables: 
$$y_1 = \begin{cases} 
      0, & y_1^*\leq 0\\
      y_1^*, & 0< y_1^* < 1000 \\
       1000, &  1000<y_1^*
   \end{cases}.
$$

$$y_2 = \begin{cases} 
      0, & y_2^*\leq 0\\
      y_2^*, & 0< y_2^* < 1000 \\
       1000, &  1000<y_2^*
   \end{cases},
$$
where
$$y_1^*=X\beta_1+\epsilon_1$$
$$y_2^*=X\beta_2+\epsilon_2.$$
Suppose I observe $y=y_1+y_2,$ and $X$. I want to estimate 
$$y=X\beta_1+\epsilon_1+X\beta_2+\epsilon_2 \equiv X\beta+\epsilon.$$
How should I go about estimating this model to get unbiased and consistent estimates of $\beta$?

Comment: There is no way to get consistent or unbiased estimates from this data. Eg suppose the $X$’s are clustered near 0 and 1, then there will be no good way to distinguish between $\beta$’s near 3000 and $\beta$’s near 4000.